# lazy_high_charts => :formatter not working for dataLabels

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code:

```
f.series(:data => @values, :dataLabels => { :formatter => "function() { return this.x; }".js_code, :enabled => true, :rotation => 90, :x=>-3, :y=>15, :color=>"#FFFFFF" } )
```

...works with the exception of the formatter function. When I add it in, the chart fails to render. Otherwise the labels are present, rotated, etc.

Not quite sure why as the very next line contains a similar formatter for tooltip which does work:

```
f.options[:tooltip][:formatter] = "function() { return ''+ this.x +': '+ this.y.toFixed(1) +' %'; }".js_code
```

Refer to: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels

UPDATE: `TypeError: f.formatter.call is not a function` is the error I see in firebug. Any idea what's up here?

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem and i solved by add

```
    <%= raw "options.tooltip.formatter = function() {
        return '<b>' + this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
      }" %>
```

in View files.

Visit [here](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts/wiki/Pie-Chart) to more advices.